# Working with django and sqlalchemy but backend mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlalchemy

I am working with python's django framework. My models are sqlalchemy and my back-end database is mysql. How will I configure them?

Comment: Do you want to use SQLAlchemy and MySQL in Django; replace the Django ORM component?

Answer (score 1):

Some links that might help you:

> http://lethain.com/entry/2008/jul/23/replacing-django-s-orm-with-sqlalchemy/
>
> http://code.google.com/p/django-sqlalchemy/
>
> http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2007/aug/26/the-django-orm-problem/
>
> http://gitorious.org/django-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

See [Django database installation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#database-installation),

> If you’re using MySQL, you’ll need MySQLdb, version 1.2.1p2 or higher. You will also want to read the database-specific notes for the MySQL backend.

And the [MySQL notes](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#id2),

> Django expects the database to support transactions, referential integrity, and Unicode (UTF-8 encoding). Fortunately, MySQL has all these features as available as far back as 3.23. While it may be possible to use 3.23 or 4.0, you'll probably have less trouble if you use 4.1 or 5.0.